# How can i use Highstock rangeSelector get the yAxis Max_value and Min_Value

Tags: highcharts

How can i use  Highstock rangeSelector get the yAxis Max_value and Min_Value ??

http://jsfiddle.net/r2wm5dyj/

$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json&callback=?', function (data) {

```
    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        title: {
            text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Using ordinal X axis'
        },

        xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: function(e) {

                $('#Sdate').html( Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.min));
                $('#Edate').html( Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.max));


            }
        }
    },

        rangeSelector : {
            buttons : [{
                type : 'hour',
                count : 1,
                text : '1h'
            }, {
                type : 'day',
                count : 1,
                text : '1D'
            }, {
                type : 'all',
                count : 1,
                text : 'All'
            }],
            selected : 1,
            inputEnabled :false
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            type: 'area',
            data : data,
            gapSize: 8,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1
            },
            fillColor : {
                linearGradient : {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops : [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            },
            threshold: null[enter link description here][1]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution in myself

```
  xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: function(e) {

                $('#Sdate').html( Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.min));
                $('#Edate').html( Highcharts.dateFormat(null, e.max));



            },
            afterSetExtremes:function(e)
            {
                  var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
                 extremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
                   $('#HiestTemp').html(extremes.dataMax);
                  $('#LowestTime').html(extremes.dataMin);


            }
        }
    },
```